# How to handle flexible inputs and returns only keys in uppercase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

The ideal output or results should be like below:

```
    >>> uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan')
    ['TWN']
    >>> uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan')
    ['TWN', 'JPN']
    >>> uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan', ltu="Lithuania")
    ['TWN', 'JPN', 'LTU']
    >>> uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan', ltu="Lithuania", svn='Slovenia')
    ['TWN', 'JPN', 'LTU', 'SVN']
```

My Code just able obtain the keys only:

```
def uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(**kwargs) -> list:
keys_only = kwargs.keys()
list_for_keys_only = list(keys_only)

return(list_for_keys_only)
```

My output:

```
>>> print(uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan'))
['twn']
>>> print(uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan'))
['twn', 'jpn']
>>> print(uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan', ltu="Lithuania"))
['twn', 'jpn', 'ltu']
>>> print(uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan', ltu="Lithuania", svn='Slovenia'))
['twn', 'jpn', 'ltu', 'svn']
```

Tried to add something like this:

```
# for k in kwargs.items():
    #     kwargs.update(k.upper())
```

but did not work. Appear to be an `AttributeError`.

Comment: use `return [k.upper() for k in list_for_keys_only]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) on `dict.keys`.

```
def uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(**kwargs):
    return list(map(str.upper, kwargs.keys()))
```

**Ouput**:

```
uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan')
# ['TWN']

uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(
    twn="Taiwan", jpn="Japan", ltu="Lithuania", svn="Slovenia"
)
# ['TWN', 'JPN', 'LTU', 'SVN']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
def uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(**kwargs) -> list:
    keys_only = kwargs.keys()
    list_for_keys_only = [k.upper() for k in keys_only]

    return(list_for_keys_only)

    
print (uppercase_keys_from_kwargs(twn='Taiwan', jpn='Japan', ltu="Lithuania"))
```

Output:

```
['TWN', 'JPN', 'LTU']
```